# How to delete Javascript object property? (BootsTrap ContexMenu var)

Tags: jquery

I have the Code to show up the contex menu by BootsTrap.
Since of some reason , I should Delete the VAR menu1 from the memory.
How to do it?
Thanks..

```
var menu1 = new BootstrapMenu('#SomeDIV', {
        actions: [{
                name: 'Action1',
                onClick: function () {
                }
            },{
                name: 'Action2',
                onClick: function () {
                }
            },{
                name: 'Action3',
                onClick: function () {
                }
            }]
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="SomeDIV">
</div>
```

Comment: What specific plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The General Answer to "How do I delete an object"

You can't, directly. All you can do is set `menu1` to another value (`undefined`, `null`) so that it no longer refers to the object, and **if** nothing else also has a reference to that same object, it will be eligible for garbage collection by the JavaScript engine (when or even whether that happens is up to the engine).

E.g., you can do:

```
menu1 = null;
```

And then provided nothing else has a reference, the object will be removed from memory.

**However**, doing that probably won't deactivate or remove the thing `new BootstrapMenu` created.

#### The Specific Answer to "How do I remove this menu"

That depends on the plugin. Most plugins have a `destroy` method you can use to destroy the thing that was built, e.g.:

```
menu1.destroy();
menu1 = null;
```

...<s>but you'll need to check the documentation for your plugin</s> and since it looks like you're using [this one](https://github.com/dgoguerra/bootstrap-menu), the good news is that although it isn't mentioned in the documentation as far as I can see, there *is* a `destroy` method visible [in the source](https://github.com/dgoguerra/bootstrap-menu/blob/master/src/BootstrapMenu.js#L418) (that link is to a line number, so will rot a bit over time).

Comment: .destroy() Is Work! 
Thanks you much...
I tried to use delete or var menu1 = null
It not work,,